# Vim in terminal behaves middle-click as paste

Tags: linux, terminal, vim

In normal mode of the Vim, I'm expecting middle-click to send the selection text as Vim's command but Vim automatically insert the text to the buffer.
How can I avoid this behavior?

For example,
selection buffer of the X window contains a Vim's command `:1,$s/ \+$//` (removing all spaces at the end of line).
When I click middle-button on the terminal, Vim does not handle it as a command but insert to the buffer.

Thanks,

Comment: Assuming that vim itself doesn't handle mouse events in your configuration, and that shift+insert behaves for you just like middle-click, this will be related to "bracketed paste mode". That's how vim knows that the data is coming from a paste operation, rather than being quickly typed. Check vim's documentation for how to turn off (more precisely: how not to turn on) bracketed paste mode. (I don't know the answer to this, sorry, but I hope I could give a useful pointer.)

Comment: Thank you, egmont, for letting me know its feature name.
As a workaround, I can disable the feature by setting TERM=screen: `env TERM=screen vim ...`
I wish there is a setting for vimrc.